# Why does using react-router-dom necessitate an import of two separate aliases of the same package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This import comes from the React Router docs:

`import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'`

I'm not sure whether I'm misunderstanding React here, or JS `import`. It seems to me that this imports a single package and makes the same package available under two separate aliases, but the `<Router>` and `<Route>` components do completely different things and don't seem to be the same in any way. What's going on here? Are `<Router>` and `<Route>` the same thing or are they different?

Comment: No, it imports JUST BrowserRouter (aliased as Router) and Route from `'react-router-dom'` - no other exports are imported (like Link, for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing two different modules from the same package. `react-router-dom` exports `Link`, `Route`, and `BrowserRouter` modules, and each provides different functionality. Your ES6 style module import statement brings in `Route` and `BrowserRouter`, and aliases `BrowserRouter` as `Router`.

Here's a brief primer on module imports: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Okay, I see. So if I was actually importing BrowserRouter with two different aliases, it would be `import { BrowserRouter as Router, BrowserRouter as Route } from 'react-router-dom'`